# Question about the antd form, I use setFieldsValue and with its help I want to insert additional data and see it in data in onFinish, how to do this?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I noticed that when I use setFieldsValue to populate fields created with Form.List, I can add extra data and see it in the onFinish data, but when I use the same approach to populate a regular form, my extra data disappears.

I need this in order to make an edit form, I load data from the server into the form for all data except id, I have a Form.Item with a name, but for id I don't want to create an invisible field, I just want to additionally add the id via setFieldsValue.

Example Form:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/basic-usage-antd-5-12-2-forked-6vstvq?file=%2Fdemo.tsx%3A26%2C25
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYH25.png)

Example FormList:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dynamic-form-nest-items-antd-5-12-2-forked-l63m3y?file=%2Fdemo.tsx%3A22%2C21
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8oIn.png)

I'm thinking of wrapping the entire form in a Form.List so that I can display additional data, but I don't think this is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it while sending the request, because the "id" doesn't concern the user, it only concerns backend. So you don't need to keep it as an actual form value.

```
 const onFinish = (values: any) => {
      const newValues = {
    ...values,
    id: 'WHATEVER'
    }
    sendAnywhere(newValues);
    };
```